# Avoid N+1 query in large data set

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a migration which updates existing records with a new attribute value. The model is called 'MyRecord'. It has millions of records in the database with a new unit_id column of null. I want to update that unit_id column with a specific value:

```
MyRecord.find_each do |record|
  unit_id = Unit.calculate_unit_from_old_columns(record.legacy_column_1, record.legacy_column_2).first.id
  record.update unit_id: unit_id
end
```

This creates a lot of N+1 queries:

```
SELECT units.* FROM units WHERE units.item_1 = 'Electronics' AND units.item_2 = 'Auto' 
UPDATE my_records SET unit_id='43' WHERE legacy_column_1 = 'Legacy Electronics' AND legacy_column_2 = 'Legacy Auto';
```

And some of these N+1 queries are duplicated. I see a lot of this in logs:

```
SELECT units.* FROM units WHERE units.item_1 = 'Electronics' AND units.item_2 = 'Auto' 
SELECT units.* FROM units WHERE units.item_1 = 'Electronics' AND units.item_2 = 'Auto'
```

I am familiar with eager loading via includes. But when this migration is run to update existing data, there will be no association yet. So I cannot do this:

```
record.includes(:unit)
```

How can I eliminate the N+1 queries and cache the query so it does not hit database again when s duplicate query?

Comment: How complicated is `calculate_unit_from_old_columns`? It'd be best to move everything to the updating query (`SET unit_id = DO_STUFF(legacy_column_1, legacy_column_2)`. If it's too complicated, you should prepare batch updates (map 1000 records to `(id, new_unit_id)` pairs and use those for update queries.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej can you give me an example of batch updates or point me to a link?

Comment: calculate_unit_from_old_columns is a named scope: scope : calculate_unit_from_old_columns, ->(item1, item2) { where(item_1: item1, item2: item_2 ) }

Comment: Oh, right, it's quite a long line. Well, you can write a simple update with join. You tagged your question with MySQL and PostgreSQL and they have different syntax for that, it should be easily searchable.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej I am using MySQL

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej I do not see how an update with join works here. The whole point of the migration is to create a relation between two tables that currently do not have a relation.

Comment: What is an "N+1 query"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-select-query-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple query, you can think of batching it if it runs for too long:

```
MyRecord.connection.execute(
  "UPDATE my_records, units 
   SET unit_id = units.id 
   WHERE units.item_1 = legacy_column_1 AND units.item_2 = legacy_column_2"
)
```